# How to update dataprovider data?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a `datagrid` with editable option set to true. If i change data in the grid view the same changes should apply to dataprovider.I am new to `flex` can any one help me to solve this.
My idea is we  need to use `ArrayCollection` properties or `itemUpdate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my code.

I have one field in the data provider. In the data grid a have added this field twice to let you see the effect of editing. If you edit values in the second column and press Enter, you can see the result in the first one.

So your data provider is always up to date.

Here is the [working example](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/dgedit/index.html).

Let me know if you meant something else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[                
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]private var myDP:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {myfield:"Hello"},
            {myfield:"World"}                
        ]);         
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:DataGrid id="myDG" x="30" y="30" height="120" dataProvider="{myDP}" editable="true">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>

            <s:GridColumn dataField="myfield" headerText="My Field" width="120"/>       

            <s:GridColumn dataField="myfield" headerText="My Field Edit" editable="true" rendererIsEditable="true" width="120">
                <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <s:GridItemRenderer>
                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[
                                import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;
                                protected function textinput_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
                                {
                                    var value:String = (event.currentTarget as TextInput).text
                                    data[column.dataField] = value; 
                                }
                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>

                        <s:TextInput text="{data['myfield']}" change="textinput_changeHandler(event)"/>

                    </s:GridItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
                </s:itemRenderer>
            </s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList> 
    </s:columns >
</s:DataGrid>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But whenever we refresh the data grid we are getting old values but how can we see the new values which we got after editing in datagrid. I think we need to save that dataprovider values in any database or is there any way to that.

Comment: Right! It depends on your server technology and data base provider. What do you use?